# Why is AWS RDS MYSQL INSERT taking READ IOPS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have db.r3.2xlarge with 4000 PIOPS. I'm inserting like 1 billion rows from EC2 instances. There are like 40GB free RAM right now.

Currently, out of 4000 PIOPS, READ PIOPS is taking 3000 and I'm only getting 1000 WRITE PIOPS. So, it's been a low writing.

How do i check which is taking READ PIOPS? And how to speed thing up?

Thank you.

Edit:

`insert ignore into dna (hash, time, song_id) values (b%s, b%s, %s)`

`I'm using self.cursor.executemany(query, rows)` from python

`hash + time + song_id` is a composite primary key.

I'm using AWS RDS InnoDB.

I have 4000 PIOPS. However, it is now stuck at 2000 total. I have 60MB/s WRITE THROUGHPUT.

Comment: show us the insert statement, tell us which type of database you are using and confirm you are actually using RDS and not a database installed on EC2

Comment: @Vorsprung, I've made the edits. Please let me know.

Comment: probably won't make any difference but you haven't said if you are using mysql or Aurora

Comment: @Vorsprung, I'm using AWS RDS MySQL InnoDB.

Answer (score 2):

If the hash is your primary key or is indexed, you're not inserting in primary my and/or index order.

Also, you're using `INSERT IGNORE`, which suggests you are trying to avoid the inevitable duplicate key error because there's duplicate data among what you're inserting.

For both of these reasons, InnoDB has to do a lot of readying to load the appropriate pages from the tablespaces on disk into memory to find the spot(s) in the primary and/or any secondary indexes where the next row needs to go, which may turn out to be wasted effort if the row is a duplicate, and may turn out to require a page split so that space is available to randomly insert the next hash into its proper place.

If hash is the primary key, it would probably be to your advantage to drop all other indexes while inserting, then add them at the end, where they can be built more efficiently.

Pre-sorting the inserts by hash should help, some, if the batches are large enough and hash is indeed the primary key.

Comment: my show create table looks like - CREATE TABLE `dna` (
  `hash` bit(26) NOT NULL,
  `time` bit(14) NOT NULL,
  `song_id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`hash`,`time`,`song_id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Comment: `bit(26)` is an interesting choice.  I assume you realize that (if my math is correct) this column can only support 67,108,864 (2^26) unique hashes.  Are you inserting the rows in sorted order by (hash,time,song_id)?

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure what you mean by sorted order. My primary key is (hash + time + song_id) so it's not just bit(26). It also considers time + song_id when deciding either it's unique or not. isn't it?